# QGIS Azimuth and Distance Plugin curve

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, cogo, metes-and-bounds, legal-description

I have just installed the Azimuth and Distance plugin for QGIS and I have been testing it for use with our COGO workload. However when using the Anti-Clockwise ArcDirection method for a curve to the left for example draws funky.  A curve to the right (clockwise works just fine). Has anyone had good luck COGO'ing parcels with legal descriptions including multiple curves left and right? You can see the overlapping hexagon is supposed to be the curve to the left. I am confused.

[image]

Comment: I had issues with the Azimuth and Distance plugin too. I gave up on using it and am now looking of alternatives. You can submit your issue to its Github page. https://github.com/mpetroff/qgsazimuth/issues https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but contacted the developers and now this has been corrected. You will need to update to version 0.9.11 of the plugin.